# BigDecimal.value of Usage

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-8

I believe there is better way  instead of the below line. But not sure of the usage.

```
aacall.setRule(new BigDecimal(a.getTotal()/ greatestcommondivisor))
```

Comment: [`aacall.setRule(BigDecimal.valueOf(a.getTotal()/ greatestcommondivisor))`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-double-)?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: Can you explain your problem or question in more detail?

Comment: You should probably do the division as `BigDecimal.divide` rather than dividing before passing to the factory.